# How to get correct output?

Tags: spring-orm

When I run the program, the below output comes.

```
{hi:9, mom:8, d:6, foo:3, ach:4, cbba:5, edf:7} null [hi:9] null [mom:8] [d:6] null [foo:3 ach:4 cbba:5] [edf:7]
```

how can I resolve this?

it shows the below output on the console.

```
{hi:9, mom:8, d:6, foo:3, ach:4, cbba:5, edf:7} null [hi:9] null [mom:8] [d:6] null [foo:3 ach:4 cbba:5] [edf:7]
```

It does not successfully run.

Comment: Please provide your existing code.

Comment: you forgot to add the program call

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.